# How can I reveal my chart tooltip programatically when the tooltip combines data from multiple series? (sync charts)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I built this demo http://jsbin.com/mewixi/5/edit?js,output to better expose my problem.

As you can see I've multiple charts with multiple series. For this demo purposes the data is the same across all the charts but that won't be the case in production.

So, because the data in all charts is related by a common "xCategory" I would like to sync the hover action on charts by highlighting that same xCategory in all charts while revealing a tooltip where data from all series is combined.

At line 182, if you comment it out you'll see that I can show a formatted tooltip for the chart being hovered. If you uncomment it you will see a better presentation of what I would like to accomplish but I don't want to show the output of a single serie.

```
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
        this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
        this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh([this]);
    };
```

Any tips on how to reveal the formatted tooltip in all charts for the same xCategory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all series within the chart and build the tooltip in a formatter callback from the points which have the same category as the hovered point.

```
formatter: function() {
      var s = [];
//      console.log(this.points);
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        var rangeValue;
        var series = point.series.chart.series;

        $.each(series, function(i, series) {
          $.each(series.data, function(j, p) {
            if (p.category === point.key) {
              if (p.high && p.low) {
                rangeValue = p.low + '~' + p.high;
              } else {
                rangeValue = p.y
              }
              s.push('<br/><span style="color:#D31B22;font-weight:bold;">' + series.name + ' : ' +
                rangeValue + '<span>');
            }
          });
        });

      });

      return s.join(' and ');
    },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ptezqnbf/2/